# Links are disabled in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an iframe that displays a full page from any website. The trouble is now that it makes all the links inside frame disabled(unlickable). I have few chunks of Javascript and CSS in it. I am not sure what is really causing the issue.

*link removed

Can someone help me out please.

Comment: check your console.. you have like 20 errors there..  :). you need to fix that first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the width on your .pageContainer  (Its actually sitting on top of the iFrame)

```
.pageContainer {  
    position: fixed;  
    width: 100%;  <-- your problem here [line 88]
    height: 100%;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. that was it. And whole time I was blaming on javascript... :)

Comment: No problem @Hassan-Z, I can see that its working now!  Looks good :)

Comment: yes, I actually tried to but it restricted me and said "can't do that within 9 minutes" ... anyways, now done.

Answer (score 2):

You are overlaying a DIV on the iFrame itself. Don't put that DIV in a fixed position.